# How to allow redirects blocked by the CORS policy in ASP.NET Core 7?

Tags: asp.net, cors, safe-stack

I am trying to figure out how to authenticate a SAFE Stack app using Azure AD. The problem is that the challenge request does a redirect to the Azure AD login page, which gets blocked by the cors policy. Right now, I am not even trying to do that, but simply trying to figure out how to get it to redirect to google. I get the following error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.google.com/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/api/ITodosApi/getTodos') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

```fs
    builder.Services.AddCors() |> ignore
    let app = builder.Build()
    app.UseCors(fun opts ->
        opts.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080").AllowCredentials().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader() |> ignore
        ) |> ignore
```

Setting the cors policy like this here doesn't seem to be doing anything. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS issue with Ambassador accessing AzureAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71798164/cors-issue-with-ambassador-accessing-azuread) You also seem to be making an unauthenticated `fetch` request that is then redirected to a logon page.

Comment: No, but I did manage to solve this particular issue. It turned out that I needed to have the Vite server proxy everything from root "/" instead of "/api". After that the redirect to Google worked. The cors middleware can be removed as they aren't related to the error. The Vite server is rewriting the origin's port from 5000 to 8080, so the browser wouldn't have any issues along those lines anyway.